# Vertical CSS3 Accordion menu not working on Android

Tags: css, input, menu, label, accordion

I'm using the menu demoed on this page: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Accordion/index2.html

Everything works great except when used on Android's default browser. When you click on a label to open up the menu, nothing happens at all.

Is there a way to force the Android browser to recognize when a label is touched so it opens?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below CSS fixed the issue strangely enough:

```
body {-webkit-animation:bugfix infinite 1s}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {from {padding:0} to {padding:0}}
```